# How can my computer automatically connect to a Wi-Fi?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, passwords, connection

I should say at the start that I'm absolutely beginner in such things like networks. I tried to search but don't really know what to type to solve the problem.

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on one of my computers (the one connected with the router). The router and the whole Wi-Fi network were 'installed' several months ago by a guy who knows a lot about IT.

I know he set the password and username or network name (?) on the Wi-Fi. But Linux automatically connected with the Internet. How is that possible? Isn't there a need to input this data on the main computer (I mean: connected with router)?

Hope it didn't connect by other way (like phone connection?) - because, you know, if it did, we may pay unimaginable costs.

Comment: Are you sure you are using your Wi-Fi and Ubuntu chose it automatically with no questions asked? What you are describing here would be very easy to do if you connect to the router with a cable/wire. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu chose it fully automatically (no dialogs). If I turn the router off, the Internet doesn't work. But yes, the computer is *currently* connected by a cable with the router. So you think isn't the password needed here?

Comment: Unplug the cable between the router and the PC and your Internet will go into the drain :)

Comment: You don't need a password for the wired connection. However, you should learn how to configure your own router. You can start by downloading the user manual from the manufacturer, or looking on the set-up cd if you received one.

Answer (score 1):

The password is only required if creating a WEP/WPA wireless connection with the router; normal wired connections do not require any authentication and will connect with no prompting unless otherwise told to in Network Manager.